# Javascript Unittesting Jasmine / Unit Testing - how do I test whether a private function has been called?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm trying to see **if** the private function has been called. Eventually I'm going to what to look for variables being set within it.

My javascript looks like the following following with a function and private function

```
mysamplefunction = function(item){

   /* figure out bla */       
   _myprivatefunction(item,bla)

}

_myprivatefunction = function(item, bla){


    /* do lots of exciting private things with item and bla */
}
```

Jasmine seems to expect the following syntax ..

```
 spyOn(mysamplefunction ,'_myprivatefunction');
```

However as we arent strictly dealing with an instance of mysamplefunction and _myprivatefunction isn't a method (its just another class) I'm not sure how to get this to work? Any ideas ??

Comment: Uh, surely a provate function is by definition an implementation detail and not something you should be testing.

Comment: @annakata In the real world it should indeed be private however I need to test it to ensure it actually works. If I was in java I would have used reflection to change the accessibilty of the methods and then I could happily run them - this type of approach doesnt seem to be possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions are declared as you describe it, I'd expect:

```
spyOn(window, '_myprivatefunction');
```

to work.

If the function is within a closure then `window` will have to become something like

```
TopLvlHeir.2ndlvel.samplefunctionpkg.publicTesting
```

The only requirement is that it is an object containing a property of `_myprivatefunction`, e.g. `firstArg[secondArg]` is a function.

Comment: I'd like to be able to spyon/check the fact that _myprivatefunction is called not to actually specifically call it.

Comment: @wmitchell, I know. My answer still stands - it's not calling the function at all. But since you've declared `_myprivatefunction` in the global scope (and is called as such) the object it belongs to is `window`. Therefore my code is spying on the `'_myprivatefunction'` property of the `window` object.

Comment: I have a ton of closures so _myprivatefunction is hidden from window but I have added it to a public interface. Something along the lines of TopLvlHeir.2ndlvel.samplefunctionpkg.publicTesting_myprivatefunction trying to then figure out what that means window in your example becomes.

Comment: @wmitchell, in that case `window` simply becomes `TopLvlHeir.2ndlvel.samplefunctionpkg.publicTesting`. The only requirement is that it is an object containing a property of `'_myprivatefunction'`, i.e. `firstArg[secondArg]` is a function.

Comment: Excellent thats what I'm after .. I'll mark accepted ! I think im going to have to post another Q tho. Im trying to get my head around Jasmine. Thanks for your help B9 !